# Pygame window is not closing

Tags: python, pygame, exit

I found a tutorial on youtube in that video the guy was running this code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Testing")

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

pygame.quit()
```

> if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

When I write "pygame.quit:" instead of "pygame.QUIT:" (In the for loop) the window doesn't close. I'm a complete beginner. Is it a command that we have to write it capitalized? Can someone explain why?

Comment: Because python, like a lot of other mainstream programming languages, is case sensitive and a variable, object or function etc. named `foo` is called `foo` and can't be accessed via `FOO` or `Foo`.

Comment: `quit` is a function and to use it you need to say `quit()`. `QUIT` is a number representing the event type and can be compared with other numbers to make decisions about what to do. They are totally different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because pygame.quit() makes the system exit and exit() closes that window.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
   if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      pygame.quit()
      exit()
```

## UPDATE

> **Event** objects have a member variable (also called attributes or properties) named **type** which tells us what kind of event the object represents. Pygame has a constant variable for each of possible types in the pygame.locals modules.

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```

Checks if the **Event** object’s **type** is equal to the constant **QUIT**

This is why we check if the Event object is a quit event, then the pygame.quit() and exit() functions are called. The pygame.quit() function is sort of the opposite of the pygame.init() function: it runs code that deactivates the Pygame library.

**TLDR; QUIT denotes a type of Event and pygame.quit() is a Function**

Comment: I meant the "pygame.QUIT:" in the for loop. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score -1):

I use this and its work

```
running = True
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
```

Comment: Please be more elaborate, provide an [explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) for your answer.

Comment: Sorry, Im a newbie but I found this code working